# Delay macro execution to when the container float is placed

Tags: floats, hooks

I need an absolutely-positioned `textblock*` and a float to appear together on the same page. When the `textblock*` is written inside the `figure`, it is executed rightaway and thus seen on the page where the `figure` appears in the code, but not where the float is finally placed. The following MWE results in the output below.

How can I delay the execution of macros, in this case of `\mytextblock`, to when the float is actually layed out? Can I somehow store and hook it to the shipout of the float?

```
\documentclass[a7paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\newcommand{\mytextblock}[1]{%
    \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0pt,0pt)
        #1
    \end{textblock*}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{figure}[p]
    Figure content
    \mytextblock{textblock content} % should appear on the same page as the figure
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: the textblock appears on the first instead of on the float page]

Instead, the the `textblock*` should be located on the page where LaTeX decided to put the float:

[image: the textblock should be located on the page where the float is placed]

Comment: Pages 9-10 of the [`textpos` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/textpos.pdf) discuss this

Comment: @mbert Thanks for the reference. The documentation discusses a different situation; the workaround there is to use `\afterpage` to put the `textblock*` on the _next_ page, but I cannot know what page LaTeX will decide to put the float on. When using `relative` mode, the `textblock` shows up on the float page, but it's cumbersome to address my actual layout needs in relative mode.

Comment: @hschmauder, sorry, don't understand, how your final result should look like. Can you please add a mock-up for better illustration? Thank you // What's the purpose of your approach, i.e. if you could do it, what will you use it for?

Comment: @MS-SPO I read it as hschmauder wants the "textblock content" to be on the same side as the "Figure content".

Comment: That‘s what I read, but can‘t imagine … too many degrees of freedom left …

Comment: @MS-SPO I updated the question to better reflect my intention, i.e., although using `absolute` mode, I want the `textblock*` to be located on the same page as the float. Since the document is long and contains many images, this may be far away, e.g. at the end of a section.

Comment: @hschmauder You can locally switch absolute and relative modes with `\TPoptions{absolute=<true|false>}`, so you can use relative mode for the float and absolute elsewhere. Though rereading you may have meant that placement for the float specifically is difficult with relative mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires a current LaTeX (with older LaTeX you can do something similar e.g. with zref) and two compilations

```
\documentclass[a7paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\mytextblock}[2]
 {
  \RecordProperties{#2}{abspage}
  \AddToHook{shipout/foreground}
   {     
     \int_compare:nNnT{\RefProperty{#2}{abspage}}={\g_shipout_readonly_int}
      {
        \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0pt,0pt)
         #1
        \end{textblock*}
      }%
   }   
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{figure}[p]
    Figure content
    \rule{1cm}{0.6\textheight}
    \mytextblock{textblock content1}{myfloat1} % 
\end{figure}

\lipsum*[1-3]

\begin{figure}[p]
    Figure content
    \rule{1cm}{0.6\textheight}
    \mytextblock{textblock content2}{myfloat2} % 
\end{figure}

    
\end{document}
```